# To do list javascript-something is wrong with my code/order

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, input

I'm building a small to do list and everything worked fine so far until I included a checkbox. now when I click on the button, nothing happens and neither do I see a checkbox. There must be something wrong with the order of code-does someone know how I need to rearrange the code and WHY?

Html code:

```
<body>
<h1>To Do List</h1>
<p><input type="text" id="textItem"/><button id="add">Add</button></p>

<ul id="todoList">
</ul>
</body>
```

Javascript code:

```
function addItem() {
  var entry = document.createElement("li");
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("input");
  checkBox.type = "checkbox";
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.innerText = entry;

  var textItem = document.getElementById("textItem");
  entry.innerText = textItem.value;
  var location = document.getElementById("todoList");

  entry.appendChild(checkBox);
  entry.appendChild(span);
  location.appendChild(entry);

}

var item = document.getElementById("add");
item.onclick = addItem;
```

Comment: The one thing I noticed was there is an error code that is thrown because there are no elements with the ID of "input"  in your <body> which you use for the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED - I've spotted 4 issues . Follow Below :

1st : When you create the check box you should be using setAttribute method to specify input type : `checkbox.setAttribute("type" , "checkbox")`

2nd : Your checkbox variable should be creating an input element  : `var checkBox = document.createElement("input");`

3rd : You should be using innerHtml instead of innerText as you are referencing a list **ELEMENT** stored in your entry variable :  `span.innerHtml = entry;`

4th: Really minor but you should grab your item and attach an event to the item before your function :

```
var item = document.getElementById("add");
item.addEventListener("click" , addItem)
```

Just change your javascript to the following :

```
var item = document.getElementById("add");
item.addEventListener("click" , addItem)

function addItem() {
  var entry = document.createElement("li");
  var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
  checkBox.setAttribute("type" , "checkbox");
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.innerHtml = entry;

  var textItem = document.getElementById("textItem");
  entry.innerText = textItem.value;
  var location = document.getElementById("todoList");

  entry.appendChild(checkBox);
  entry.appendChild(span);
  location.appendChild(entry);

}
```

Example Here : http://codepen.io/theConstructor/pen/pyPdgg

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks! Why should I use the evenlistener? If I just use your code and leave                                                                                                             var item = document.getElementById("add");
item.onclick = addItem;                                                                                      as I had, im getting a weird result:[object HTMLLIElement]

Comment: I've  updated my code to reflect ... check the link again .

Comment: Thanks!! Do you know how I can make the box appear on the left side and not on the right one?

Comment: Yes just float the span left in your css style sheet . The styling will be applied once the element is loaded within the dom .

Comment: I tried -                                                                                                             li     span {
float:left;     
}                                                                                                                           but nothing happens..

Comment: sorry i read too fast . apply float:left to --->>>  input[type="checkbox"]

Comment: Okay cool thanks a lot! If I could as one more thing- I wanted to include 2 more buttons- one for saving all the inputs and one for showing all the saved inputs.. I thought I would save all in an array by looping through them  but neither works my save nor showing button

Comment: var array=[];
    function saveList() {
    for (var i=0; i<entry.length; i++) {
     array.push(entry[i]);
     }

    }
   function showed () {
   console.log("array");
    }
    var item = document.getElementById("add");
    item.onclick = addItem;
    var saved=document.getElementById("save");
    saved.onclick=saveList;
    var showed=document.getElementById("show");
    showed.onclick=showList;